# problema del agente viajero

Tags: python, lista, bucles

Tengo el siguiente código que se comporta de la siguiente manera:

Tengo una etapa base y para hallar la siguiente etapa en la posición `t+1`, se elige la celda de la posición actual de la etapa base, se le suma el valor que tiene la posición `i+1` y la posición `i-1`, todo esto módulo 2.

El problema es que solamente me imprime de forma correcta la primera fila.

```
iteracion = 0
print("CONDICIÓN INICIAL: " + str(etapaBase) + "\n")
while(iteracion < 5):

    for i in range(len(etapaBase)):

         #Validación para cuando se encuetre en la primera posición


        if(i<len(etapaBase)-1):
            suma = etapaBase[i-1] + etapaBase[i] + etapaBase[i+1]
            valor = suma % 2
            etapaSiguiente[i] = valor



    iteracion = iteracion + 1

    etapaBase = etapaSiguiente

    print("                   " + str(etapaBase))
```

Comment: Solo describiste el agente viajero y colocaste el código, tienes que plantear el problema que tú estás presentando, qué le sucede a ese código, que quieres obtener y que estás obteniendo. Así se te puede ayudar con mayor facilidad. Coloca un titulo adecuado para tu problema.

Comment: Hola Fabio he revertido la edición, no edites una pregunta para cambiarla por completo cuando ya hay respuestas, esto deja toda respuesta y comentario sin contexto en absoluto. Crea una nueva pregunta en su lugar, además ten en cuenta lo comentado por @vpaternina cuando lo hagas. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que la línea:

```
etapaBase = etapaSiguiente
```

no hace lo que crees que hace.

En Python un variable es solo un nombre asociado a una referencia a un objeto en memoria. La línea anterior solo hace que ambas variables apunten al mismo objeto (a la misma lista). Cuando en la siguiente iteración vas modificando `etapaSiguiente` modificas también `etapaBase`.

Simplemente asigna una copia de la lista:

```
etapaBase = etapaSiguiente[:]
```

o reasigna una nueva lista a `etapaSiguiente`:

```
etapaBase = etapaSiguiente
etapaSiguiente = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

de ambas formas cada variable apuntará a objetos distintos. `etapaSiguiente[:]` crea una copia superficial (copia el objeto lista pero no sus items), como en este caso los items son enteros (inmutables) no hay problema. Es equivalente a `etapaSiguiente.copy()`.

Si te interesa, el código puede reducirse usando el operador módulo para evitar indizar sobre índices inválidos:

```
etapa_base = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] 
etapa_siguiente = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

print(f"CONDICIÓN INICIAL: {etapa_base}\n")
len_eta = len(etapa_base)
for _ in range(5):
    for i, value in enumerate(etapa_base):
        etapa_siguiente[i] = (
            (etapa_base[i - 1] + value + etapa_base[(i + 1) % len_eta]) % 2
            )
    etapa_base = etapa_siguiente[:]
    print(f"                   {etapa_base}")
```